# Plot with margin text that scales for multiple plots?

Tags: r, plot

I've created a figure with two y-axes, and use mtext() to label the right-hand axis.

```
# generate some data to plot
x <- 1:5
y1 <- rnorm(5)
y2 <- rnorm(5,20)

# set margins
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)

# plot first x/y line
plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red")

#plot second x/y line
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y2,,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("y2",side=4,line=3)
```

This works great by itself.  However, if you place this into a figure with multiple plots:

```
# create a 3x3 figure for multiple plots
par(mfrow = c(3, 3))

# generate some data to plot
x <- 1:5
y1 <- rnorm(5)
y2 <- rnorm(5,20)

# set margins
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)

# plot first x/y line
plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red")

#plot second x/y line
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y2,,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("y2",side=4,line=3)
```

Here, the left-hand y-axis label gets smaller, while the right-hand axis does not.

I am aware that the source of this behavior is that the `cex` parameter in `mtext()` is NOT relative to `par("cex")`; what I'd like is some way around this.

Comment: Doing multiple plots with `par(mfrow = ...)` is a world of pain. Try using the `ggplot2` or `lattice` libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to use the `par()$cex` attribute. So your code would be:

```
x <- 1:5
y1 <- rnorm(5)
y2 <- rnorm(5,20)

par(mfrow = c(3, 3), mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y2,,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("y2",side=4,line=3, cex=par()$cex)
```